# File keeps on giving an error

Tags: java

I try to run my file but it's giving me the error below

```
try{

        Connection con = (Connection)DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/SOCIETY","root","");
        PreparedStatement query = null;
        query = con.prepareStatement("select * from users");
        ResultSet rs = query.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            String User = jTextField1.getText();
            String Pwd = new String(jPasswordField1.getPassword());


            String uname = rs.getString("Username");
            String Password = rs.getString("Password");

            if((User.equals(uname))&& Pwd.equals(Password))
            {
                new LOGINPAGE().setVisible(true);

            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Incorrect Username or Password!");
            } 
        }
        con.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The error I get is

> java.lang.ClassException:java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.long

Comment: Please include the complete stacktrace of the exception, as it says **where** the error happens. It doesn't look like it happens anywhere in your code example.

Comment: Given the error message, are you sure you've given us all the code you wrote? I mean that neither `BigDecimal` nor `long` are used in your example...

Comment: Aren't you doing a `SELECT COUNT(*)` somewhere? this would return a BigInteger.